# Mongoose throw error - how to fix this?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In my app, I am using `mongoose` to connect with `mlab` to post the data. when I use the postman to test the post, I am getting the data updated in the data base. but the console throws this error :

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'code' of null
    at C:\Tutorials\try\NodePractical\MEAN-Family\app\routes\api.js:42:13
    at C:\Tutorials\try\NodePractical\MEAN-Family\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:3336:16
    at C:\Tutorials\try\NodePractical\MEAN-Family\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:1927:18
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:349:13)
```

I am not able to understand this error at all. How to fix this? And what is wrong with my code here?

For the reference here is my `post` api which I am using:

```
.post(function( req, res ){

                var family = new Family();

                family.username = req.body.username,
                family.password = req.body.password,
                family.familyLeader = req.body.familyLeader,
                family.husband = req.body.husband,
                family.wife = req.body.wife,
                family.kids = req.body.kids;

                family.save(function(err) {

                    if (err.code == 11000) {
                        return res.json({ success: false, message: 'A user with that username already exists. '});
                    }
                    else {
                        res.send( err );
                    }

                    res.json({ message: 'Family created!' });

                });



            })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because every node callback have this signature `callback(error, response)`,

this means that if an error occurs, the first parameter will contain the error and the second will be null. But if no error occurs, the **first parameter will be null**, which mean that in this case you're trying to access the property `.code` of a null variable.

To prevent this, you can first check if error isn't null, by doing this:

```
family.save(function(err, newFamily) {

    if (err) {
        if(err.code == 11000) {
            return res.json({ success: false, message: 'A user with that username already exists. '});
        }
        else {
            return res.send( err );
        }
    }

    res.json({ message: 'Family created!', newFamily: newFamily });

});
```

Pay attention to the changes:

- first line - I included the second parameter, which contains the save family
- second line - the first condition check if `err` isn't null
- last line - I included the `newFamily` at the response, which is a good practice.

Comment: Yes, It's working. But I am not getting the `success` message, ( `Family created ` ) with new family details. ( db creates the new data )

Comment: @JohnnyHK was right. Please see the updated now, I fixed the error check. Now this might work.

Answer (score 0):

Write this in your callback function

```
                if (err && err.code == 11000) {
                    return res.json({ success: false, message: 'A user with that username already exists. '});
                }
                else if (err){
                    res.send( err );
                }else{

                res.json({ message: 'Family created!' });}
```